# Scale one dimension of EPS and preserve label font and size

Tags: eps

I'm importing .eps in LaTeX. I want to resize image to fit my purposes. I want to do that only by one scale, *X* or *Y* (disproportional).
The problem is that labels (font and size) become distorted.

Is there some way to change *one* scale (e.g. width) and to keep labels as they in original?

Comment: This is a nasty issue in my opinion. If you have your figure in a vector drawing software then together with the `\psfrag` command, you can work on the fonts in your LaTeX code itself.

Answer (score 4):

No matter which way you scale, the fonts etc. used in the image will also be affected by that scaling. Here is an example, substitute your own image

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\newlength\mylen
\settoheight\mylen{\includegraphics{x-1}}
\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=\mylen]{x-1}
\includegraphics{x-1}
\end{document}
```

I used this metapost code, and ran it through `mptopdf`

```
beginfig(1);
label(btex "This is some text" etex, origin);
endfig;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I will have to work on the .eps file, instead of LaTex.